# Why can't I get the AnimationTree node?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-4

This is my code:

```
extends CharacterBody2D


@export var SPEED = 300.0
@export var maxHP = 100
@export var curHP = 100

var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")
var state_machine = $AnimationTree.get("parameters/playback")

func _ready():
    pass


func _physics_process(delta):
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity * delta
    
    var direction = Input.get_axis("ui_left", "ui_right")
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
    
    if velocity.length() > 0:
        state_machine.travel("run")
    else:
        state_machine.travel("idle")
        
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        $Sprite2D.set("flip_h", true)
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        $Sprite2D.set("flip_h", false)
    
    
    move_and_slide()
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("attack"):
        _shoot()

func _losehp():
    curHP -= 10

func _die():
    if curHP == 0:
        pass

func _shoot():
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("attack"):
        pass
```

I get errors on the line:

```
var state_machine = $AnimationTree.get("parameters/playback")
```

These are the errors:

[image]

> CharacterBody2D.gd:9 @ @implicit_new(): Node not found: "AnimationTree" (relative to "CharacterBody2d").

[image]

> Cannot call method `get` on a null value.

the tree:
[image]

please help:(

Comment: Please use formatted text for error messages rather than screenshots/images. Right clicking an error brings up a context menu with the option to copy the error & the debugger has a square looking icon for copying.

Comment: As for the error: What does the scene tree look like? (note: the scene tree is one of the things in Godot where it makes sense to include a screenshot/image as it includes a lot of icons). Based on where you making the function call, you probably need to be using the `@onready` annotation, but we can't know for sure because you haven't included any information / description about your scene(s) or what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Pikalek there's another error when i changed the script to theraot's  . here's the error:
W 0:00:00:0822   _transition_to_next_recursive: AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback: parameters/playback aborts the transition by detecting one or more looped transitions in the same frame to prevent to infinity loop. You may need to check the transition settings.
  <C++ Source>   scene/animation/animation_node_state_machine.cpp:928 @ _transition_to_next_recursive()

Comment: but ill fix it.

Comment: At a glance, I don't see the what causes the error you posted in the above comment... Yet, searching it took me here: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/82935 - see if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
var state_machine = $AnimationTree.get("parameters/playback")
```

The expression `$AnimationTree` is equivalent to `get_node("AnimationTree")`, which is trying to access the scene tree.

However, the aforementioned line will run before the `CharacterBody2D` is in the scene tree. To solve this, you can use `@onready`:

```
@onready var state_machine = $AnimationTree.get("parameters/playback")
```

Then, assuming the the `AnimationTree` is there (you didn't share how the scene tree looks like in your project), it should work.

Comment: it worked! there are no errors but the animations seem not to play for some reason but i think i coded it wrong. but thanks!